# Keyboard shortcut to add a div with a css class in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

In visual studio code, as well as other IDE's such as JetBrains, there is a keyboard shortcut where you can type ".[classname]" + tab and it will produce a `<div class="classname"></div>` element on your html page. I have been looking for something similar in VS2019 but have not found anything that does this. Is there such a shortcut in VS2019?

Comment: Maybe you should check out [ZenCoding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ZenCoding) for visual studio

Comment: VS has code snippets for this. They are very simple to write, and will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The closest would be to type div.your_class.another_class then hit enter

Comment: I tried this and it did not do anything in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you working inside an html file?

Comment: of course. I was inside the cshtml file.

Comment: that is for VS Code, it does not work like that in VS2019

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, select Extensions, manage extensions, then search for **Zencoding** and install that extension.

After restarting and installing the extension, you can now do the same as in VS Code.  See for more reference: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ZenCoding